# HTML page resolves relative links as if in the root directory

Tags: html, spring, spring-boot, jsp

A Spring Boot web application has its root path `/ra`. The root of its static files is in the server-side directory `src/main/webapp`.

A page `index.jsp` located in `src/main/webapp/console` and having its web address `/ra/console` has a relative link to a file `script.css` in the same subdirectory `src/main/webapp/console`:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=utf-8" pageEncoding="utf-8"%>
<!doctype html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="script.css">
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

I reduced the page to a test case, to be sure that there is nothing in it which causes the problem.

The page is retrieved via a Spring Boot controller with `@RequestMapping(value = "/console")` which returns `"console/index"`. **It worked since ever the app existed.** Now the page behaves as if it were located in `src/main/webapp`. See this screenshot made using Chrome 87 on Linux:
[image: screenshot]

The browser sees the page at `/ra/console` (address bar) but then, it sees the css with the relative path `script.css` at `/ra/script.css` (status line). Of course, `script.css` is located in the same directory as the page calling this, that is, in the directory `src/main/webapp/console` or at the address `/ra/console/script.css` (and the browser sees `script.css` there if the address is typed manually).

There is evidently no redefinition of `base` anywhere in the HTML file. What might I have changed that made the browser resolve relative paths like that? Is it my error or some bug in the combination SpringBoot/JSP which has suddenly shown? I used that combination many times as described [here](https://dzone.com/articles/spring-boot-2-with-jsp-view) and I had never problems with it.

Comment: It looks like browser identifies the `/ra/console` as `console` file in the `/ra/` directory. Try using `/ra/console/` (with the trailing slash).

Comment: You are right! I did not even think about `/` because it turned out that `/ra/console` hit the breakpoint at `return "console/index"` in the controller. Could you explain why both addresses go through the same controller, but behave differently?

Comment: I guess that the browser just sees the address line, which is not influenced by the server response.